# Is there an easy way to overwrite base directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm looking for the simple way to overwrite behaviour of directives provided out of box, for example `ngIf`

So I can make a child directive and extend the behaviour and after declare as a native one.

P.S.: I know that overwriting standard functionality is VERY BAD practice, but I'm doing it just for study/research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to write your own ngIf like myIf

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myIf]'
})
export class MyIfDirective {

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
  }

  @Input()
  set myIf(val) {
    if(val) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

then

```
<div *myIf="isVisible">
    Hi there!
</div>
```

---

or this would help

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import {NgIf} from "@angular/common"

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngIf][myNgIf]'
})
export class myNgIf extends NgIf {

  @Input() myNgIf: boolean;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {

    super(viewContainer, templateRef);
  }


  @Input()
  set ngIf(val) {
    if (val) {
      ...
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm looking the way to overwrite existing directive

Comment: yes, it's better, but it still does not overwrite existing one. Let's assume that we already have a project with ngIfs there and now I just want to change the behaviour in all the places

Comment: You just nees to import this one. Apparently you cannot do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: everything is possible, it only matter of solution ugliness :)

Comment: @StepanSuvorov you may create another directive which would use the same selectors as an Angular's one and then you can extend behaviour since both directives would apply this.

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to extend the already provided behaviour, it is possible to do that pretty easily. You just need to create your custom directive and use the selector for example `[ngIf]`.

But element you used the directive on is still associated with the original `ngIf`. So you won't get a nice and clean solution to get rid of the original behaviour.
You can see an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trying-to-override-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

To really override there are these solutions that may be somehow usable and not a hack

1. Reimplement/extend the directive by yourself and import it in a module instead of the original one

   - in case of `ngIf` that would mean creating custom `CommonModule` which exposes this directive from the angular core
2. Use the "adjusted" fork of angular
3. Use regex to find all occurrences of the desired directive (for example `ngIf`) and replace it with some custom name, that you can easily use in the selector (`[myNgIf]`)